# Can a certificate of an android keystore be calculated from its fingerprint?

Tags: android, keytool

Using Keytool and openssl,

Given the following certificate's fingerprint of an android debug certificate:

`MD5:  AD:CC:28:BE:3F:E9:CD:ED:2C:07:9E:C7:44:8E:C2:44
SHA1: 43:F6:F1:D9:2C:83:5E:F3:44:B0:99:6C:28:B8:94:DA:71:FB:DD:4B
SHA256:3D:D0:AA:2B:A7:50:00:D9:64:CC:FF:F3:75:67:FB:0B:39:13:F6:8D:CC:47:55:5E:56:EB:0B:5E:61:96:0F:71`

And given the SHA1 hash of the certificate, written in base 64 (using `openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`):

`2Zbz2SyIGvNEsDRhKLiU2nH73Us0`

Can I calculate a fingerprint to get the certifiace and vise versa to verify the certificate and its fingerprint?

Comment: That is not a certificate.

Comment: i have added the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot reverse a hash function. But given several candidate certificates you could hash each of them and find out for which one the hash matches.